# How can i extract the an image i have uploaded using the UploadItem in SmartGWT, as a byte array?

Tags: smartgwt

I would like to get the binary content of an image i uploaded using the UploadItem of SmartGWT but the UploadItem.getValue() method returns only the URL of the image. I looked through the API and there doesnt seem to be a method that can achieve what i require. Did i miss something? Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

For me the behavior you get is normal the value you get is the value of the formItem i.e what had been input so in your case the url of the image. To get the binary content you need to set your form with the right encoding, the right http method and submit the form. On the server side you have to process the request, send back the image content. Back on the client on the  submitComplete event you have to recover the image content inside the response.
Personaly I never mix `gwt` widget and `smartgwt`  except for upload (I don't really remember why....:) ) where I use the gwt `FileUpload`.
Hope it could help

Comment: Thanks Alain Buferne. I think i was looking for a way to extract the content before submitting the form on the client side. Apparently doesnt work that way. Thanks nway